# ASP.NET Core EF LINQ - Can I break up a large query statement and still have it execute once

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've been under the impression that if I write the following code:

```
filteredClients = _clientAPIRepository.AllIncluding(s => s.Jobs, s => s.Suburb);
```

it will execute the statement passing the contents into filteredClients at which time I then want to filter on a number of columns using where clauses.

My original understanding was that it shifts the entire table into memory rather than doing all the work on the DB server. I'm interested in efficiency here and want to execute the query once on the DB and not have to go back because I added a where clause etc. So I've tried to create a large one off statement to try and meet this intention however...

I then came across [this answer from Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7972418/5750758) indicating that EF queries are not immediately executed until you start to use the results.

I am in the position where I don't know what the shape of the query will look like.. the person could filter on one column or several as well as sort on one or several columns.

As mentioned, I have tried to filter using a single query while trying to take into account the fact that some of the where clauses are not needed as per below.

```
        filteredClients = _clientAPIRepository.AllIncluding(s => s.Jobs, s => s.Suburb)
        .Where(c => c.ClientNo.ToString().StartsWith(clientFilters.ClientNo) || clientFilters.ClientNo == string.Empty)
        .Where(c => c.CompanyName.StartsWith(clientFilters.ClientLastName) || clientFilters.CompanyName == string.Empty)
        .Where(c => c.MobilePhone.StartsWith(clientFilters.MobilePhone) || clientFilters.MobilePhone == string.Empty);
```

..and I need to add sorting to this as well.

If I start with this query (with predicates):

```
filteredClients = _clientAPIRepository.AllIncluding(s => s.Jobs, s => s.Suburb);
```

and then, a little later in the method, I add a `where` clause to it like:

```
filteredClients.where.Where(c => c.ClientNo.ToString().StartsWith(clientFilters.ClientNo));
```

..and so on building up the query - based on what filters and orderby's have been selected which I can do in my method..

I would like to know if I can build the query gradually, adding `where` clauses and orderbys based solely on whats been sent from the webpage.. AND, when the query is executed.. AND, if its executed once or more than once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can build queries gradually and without executing them. I believe this is called [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution#deferred-query-execution). Basically, Linq queries against a data source create an `IQueryable<Type>` object that you can pass around and modify. This just builds a bunch of SQL commands, instead of getting the actual results. 
Then you can execute it by calling one of the functions such as `ToList`, `ToDictionary`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Average`, `Sum`, etc. Enumerating over the `IQueryable` (e.g. `foreach`) will also cause it to execute. So as long as the context that you are querying against is not disposed, you can add as many `where` or `orderby` clauses as you need and execute it when you're done.
Example from the link:

```
using (AdventureWorksEntities context = new AdventureWorksEntities())
{
    IQueryable<Product> productsQuery =
        from p in context.Products
        select p;

    IQueryable<Product> largeProducts = productsQuery.Where(p => p.Size == "L");

    Console.WriteLine("Products of size 'L':");
    foreach (var product in largeProducts) // <-- Query is not executed until here
    {
        Console.WriteLine(product.Name);
    }
}
```